# Creating an event in an Android calendar using String date and time

Tags: android, android-calendar

My date and time is in this format below. How can i add them into my calendar as Begin Time and End Time. The event starts and ends on the same day.

```
String date = "2014-07-20";
String time = 14:00-17:00;
```

I want to add them in:

```
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, ___);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, ____);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one option is to use joda time:

```
DateTime startTime=DateTime.parse(yourStartTime);
DateTime endTime=DateTime.parse(yourEndTime);
```

and then use getMillis()

```
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime.getMillis());
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getMillis());
```